# How to fix stop promise returned in .catch beeing processed in the .then block of the preceding promise. Ie .catch should stay in .catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Then a promise calls another promise and the inner promise returns from catch the outer one processes in the .then block

I have searched here and google generally.
Tried to use a simple try.. catch. But will not work with calling a promise

```
assignResolver(data)

      .then(function(resp) {
        console.log("map then");
        console.log(resp);
       })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("map catch");
        console.log(err);
      });

export async function assignResolver(data) {
  csrf();

  return api
    .post("/api/task/assignResolver", data)
    .then(function(res){
      console.log("in api then block");
      return res.data;
    } )
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("in api then block");
      console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `throw` the error again, when inside the inner `catch`, and it'll be handled in the outer `catch`, and not the outer `.then`:

```
export async function assignResolver(data) {
  csrf();

  return api
    .post("/api/task/assignResolver", data)
    .then(function(res){
      console.log("in api then block");
      return res.data;
    } )
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("in api then block");
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
  });
}
```

But this is a bit strange to do - it usually makes more sense to `catch` in only one place. For example, if `assignResolver` *really needs* to be able to do something specific when encountering an error, and your outer caller needs to be able to do something *else* when encountering the error as well, having two `catch`es can be an option, but in most cases, you can just have a single `catch` wherever the error can be handled properly.

Here, unless `assignResolver` itself needs to do something on encountering the error, leave out its `catch` entirely:

```
export async function assignResolver(data) {
  csrf();

  return api
    .post("/api/task/assignResolver", data)
    .then(function(res){
      console.log("in api then block");
      return res.data;
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume that I can throw the HTTP code that caused the original error

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah, probably. It depends on if OP is actually doing something significant in the `assignResolver` catch block. If it's just dummy code, and something significant is actually being done there, the double `catch`es could make sense, but that's usually not the case, in which case just having the outer `catch` is definitely best.

Comment: Thank you this resolved the issue. The corrective action needs to occur in the outer function as this presents a growl message based on the HTTP code. (nb I was simply logging the where the error 1st showed in react. It  was generated in the Rails API)

Answer (score 0):

`.catch` is meant to *handle the error*, so afterwards the promise chain will continue regularily with the next `.then`. To continue with the next `.catch` you have to re`throw` the error from inside the `.catch` or return a rejected promise.